# Magento: adding catalog price rules to options of a bundle

Tags: magento

I've looking around and couldn't find how to do this.

I'd like to be able to set a catalog price rule for a specific option of a bundled product.  Basically I want to set the price of any selection from option1 to be $0 in that bundle (but keep the price the same for that product if someone just adds the product to their cart from outside of the bundle).  is there a way to do this that i'm missing?

The second approach I was thinking was to set the price to $0 of all those selections for that option (i saw a post on here on how to do something like that programatically) although without testing that that works, it seems like it wouldn't.

any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that Magento does not do by default. Additionally, beware of trying to change this through cleverness, as Magento has significant validation for prices once items are added to the cart (e.g. it will try to recalibrate them to the database on every page load). It sounds like trying to restructure the flow so that you aren't trying to use the shopping cart rules might be the best bet here. Would it be possible to use some other mechanism to give discounts, like a coupon code?

Comment: the problem with a coupon code is that I can only apply one correct?  If the user buys this bundled product and I apply the coupon code, then if they buy 2 of these bundled products only one coupon code is used.

Also I tried to just use a cart rule that applied to the bundled product sku to discount by a certain $ but it actually applies the discount to every single item inside the bundled product.  any idea how i could just get it to apply once per bundled product sku?